# Recommendation for hosting Git VCS from my drupal installation

Tags: 7, drush, version-control

Our community does a lot of coding work (lua, c#, php, etc) and we are looking to move away from the usual repo hosts (BitBucket/GitHub/Jenkins) and make our website more of an all-in-one experience. I've been trying to find guides for hosting a git repo and browser from a drupal installation, but all I can seem to find is installing/updating drupal with git. Are there any modules for hosting a personal git repo?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Case Tracker](https://www.drupal.org/project/casetracker) for project SCM hosting from Drupal:

> Case Tracker enables teams to track outstanding cases which need
>   resolution. This module was inspired by the issue handling in project
>   module, but unlike Project module, which is specific to software
>   development, Case Tracker was designed to be a generic issue tracker.
>
> Case Tracker is usable right out of the box as a basic ticketing
>   system, it's default UI is minimal but feature complete. The module
>   was designed to be extended by programmers and site builders to meet
>   complex needs, and so tries to avoid making too many assumptions about
>   all the ways it can be used.
>
> Drupal 7
>
> 7.x-2.x - it is an Entity based approach(#1653184: Case Tracker 7.x-2.x - a new approach, with entities) and is on heavy development. As it's based on Entity API, it has a deeper integration with Views,
>   Rules, Message and a lot of other modules natively.
>   7.x-1.x - has the content types for Project and Cases working without problems. The Notifications, Actions and View integration that needs
>   to be tested.

This module is D6 specific but look at [Case Tracker Commits](https://www.drupal.org/project/casetracker_commits) as well.

See also [Project](https://www.drupal.org/project/project) which powers Drupal.org itself, and the modules it uses such as [Versioncontrol Project](https://www.drupal.org/project/versioncontrol_project) and its dependant modules.